Laravel Filament v3: Property type not supported in Livewire for property
I'm upgrading my Laravel / Filament app from v2 to v3 (with Laravel 11, mysql, PHP 8.3).
Now I'm getting this error:
Property type not supported in Livewire for property: ["0.0000"] 

The problem seems to be my Laravel Custom Cast of decimal type (As I use the php-decimal extension https://php-decimal.github.io):
Project Model, with an example of a failing column:
protected function casts(): array
{
    return ['investment' => DecimalZeroCast::class,];
}

which is defined as this
class DecimalZeroCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    /**
     * Cast the given value.
     */
    public function get(Model $model, string $key, mixed $value, array $attributes): Decimal
    {
        return is_null($value) ? new Decimal(0) : (is_float($value) ? new Decimal((string) $value) : new Decimal($value));
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the given value for storage.
     */
    public function set(Model $model, string $key, mixed $value, array $attributes): float
    {
        return is_null($value) ? 0 : ($value instanceof Decimal ? $value->toFixed(12) : $value);
    }
}

In the mysql database the column is defined as decimal(24,12).
I've already found out, that this is a Livewire thing, that Livewire can not handle complex types: https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/7465
What I found out:

The problem already occurs when loading the Model in Filament.
Excluding the column from the Eloquent Query is no option, as I need the data.
Defining a separate Accessor in Laravel does not resolve the issue, as the column is still loaded and hydrated by filament.
Changing the column type in mysql (decimal) is not really an option, as there is a lot of logic built with this decimal extension which works great.


Dan Harrin's answer on github pointed me to the right direction https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/3490 to use mutate hooks https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/editing-records
My solution is to mutate the decimal to a float in the hook where the Filament Form is filled:
EditProject.php
protected function mutateFormDataBeforeFill(array $data): array
{
    $data['investment'] = $data['investment']->toFloat(); 

    return $data;
}

